# Parallel tasks execution print order

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is an example taken from MSDN about tasks:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class CustomData
{
   public long CreationTime;
   public int Name; 
   public int ThreadNum;
}

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Task[] taskArray = new Task[10];
      for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++) {
         taskArray[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew( (Object obj ) => 
                        {
                            CustomData data = obj as CustomData;
                            if (data == null) 
                                return;

                            data.ThreadNum = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                         },
                         new CustomData() {Name = i, CreationTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks});
      }
      Task.WaitAll(taskArray);     
      foreach (var task in taskArray) {
         var data = task.AsyncState as CustomData;
         if (data != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} created at {1}, ran on thread #{2}.",
                              data.Name, data.CreationTime, data.ThreadNum);
      }                     
   }
}
```

The example displays output like the following:

```
//       Task #0 created at 635116412924597583 on thread #3.
//       Task #1 created at 635116412924607584 on thread #4.
//       Task #3 created at 635116412924607584 on thread #4.
//       Task #4 created at 635116412924607584 on thread #4.
//       Task #2 created at 635116412924607584 on thread #3.
//       Task #6 created at 635116412924607584 on thread #3.
//       Task #5 created at 635116412924607584 on thread #4.
//       Task #8 created at 635116412924607584 on thread #4.
//       Task #7 created at 635116412924607584 on thread #3.
//       Task #9 created at 635116412924607584 on thread #4.
```

I don't understand why in this example there's a possibility that the tasks won't print in the natural order of 0 1 2 3.. If every cell in the array gets an object with the iterator value then why does it matter even if every task runs in a different time? They still each get a state with the loops iterator value..

Link to the example:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please try and format your question. As presently laid out its near impossible to follow.

Comment: Did you run this code yourself and reproduced the order? Because in MSDN examples anything can be written, not necessary related to reality.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 you're right.. done.

Comment: @Evk I still can't run it myself.. and I think you're wrong since if there's only one possibility of output they won't write "output like the following"

Comment: I mean MSDN examples are not always correct, there can be errors of different kinds there, typos and so on. Can you include the link to that msdn example in the question? All in all I don't see any possibility for that code to produce that output.

Comment: I've edited with the link. Search there for "asyncstate"

Comment: They've just copy-pasted output from previous example as is (note that all CreationTime values are identical in two outputs, so that is certainly copy-paste). In previous example Console.WriteLine is inside task delegate itself so indeed can produce given output. So as I said - just minor error caused by mindless copy-pasting in MSDN examples.

Comment: So you're also thinking that the output must be in order?

Comment: Yes I'm quite sure it is in order. You can run yourself if you are not sure. Since they copy-pasted output from previous example (because of the same timestamps) - their output cannot be trusted anyway and can be ignored.

Comment: @Evk if you want, you can add what you wrote as an answer and I'll accept it.